# Anonymous Function without Types in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I don't fully understand the following code. I can identify there is a trailing closure. I don't know why

1. the function type is missing
2. images is not a function.

but it's valid.

```
    self.getImages(request) { images in // this line I don't understand
        if let images = images {
            // do something

        } else {
            // do something
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read it like this:

```
 self.getImages(request, completion:{ images in // this line I don't understand
    if let images = images {
        // do something

    } else {
        // do something
    }
})
```

`images` is the parameter of your closure.

This syntax is called trailing closure, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102) documentation.